# A class instance is a reference type and struct is a value type C#. Is it also applicable for C++

Tags: c#, c++, class, struct

The article [Passing a struct and passing a class to a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-know-the-difference-passing-a-struct-and-passing-a-class-to-a-method) says that a class instance is a reference type and struct is a value type in C# and I try to replicate the same in the C++ to get to know about the behaviour of struct and class instances when passed in a method.

What I figure out is that in C++ you have to pass the class with as a reference to achieve the same result, Otherwise, it will take the struct and class instance as pass by value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TheClass
{   
    public:
        std::string willIChange;
};

struct TheStruct
{
    std::string willIChange;
};

void ClassTaker(TheClass *c)
{
    c -> willIChange = "Changed";
}

void StructTaker(TheStruct s)
{
    s.willIChange = "Changed";
}

int main()
{
    TheClass testClass;
    TheStruct testStruct;

    testClass.willIChange = "Not Changed";
    testStruct.willIChange = "Not Changed";

    ClassTaker(&testClass);
    StructTaker(testStruct);

    cout << "\n Class field = " << testClass.willIChange;
    cout << "\n Struct field = " << testStruct.willIChange;

    return 0;
}
/* Output:
Class field = Changed
Struct field = Not Changed
*/
```

I want to know more about the *Type* of struct and class instances. Please help me out to understand this.

Comment: No, it isn't. C# and C++ are completely different languages, with very little in common.

Comment: Relevant: [Does C++ treat Class Objects like value types if initialized without the new operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13633824/11683)

Comment: The problem can be in used type. `struct` is copied even in C++ *(at least in some cases)*, but in C# is `string` immutable, but the class `std::string` can have a different behaviour. *(Did not really test it.)* Try to use `int` in the example.

Comment: 'class' and 'struct' are ridiculously similar in C++ (a couple of minor differences regarding default access and inheritance). The only reason it was included in C++ was that Stroustrup intended for C++ to be compatible with C and omitting struct would've broken that.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one real difference between a `class` and a `struct` in C++. In a `class` the default visibility is `private` and in a `struct` the default visibility is `public`. Typically, C++ programmers use these to express different things. Most of the time if you see a C++ programmer write something as a `struct` it will be a dumb object meant to have it's fields accessed directly. Ex:

```
struct Point {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
};
Point p;
p.x = 1;
p.y = 10;
```

When the same programmer writes a `class` they're trying to encapsulate some behavior.

```
class Point {
  int x_ = 0;
  int y_ = 0;
 public:
  Point(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
  void Draw();
  void Translate(int x, int y);
}
Point p{10, 5};
p.Translate(1, -3);
p.Draw();
```

Both of the above could be implemented while swapping `class` for `struct` and updating the visibility.

As a random note on your example...

```
F(SomeType* x) { x->SomeThing(); }
```

is a pass by pointer, not by reference.

```
F(SomeType& x) { x.SomeThing(); }
```

is a pass by reference (`&`).

```
F(SomeType x) { x.SomeThing(); }
```

is a pass by value, which typically creates a copy as written.

When you call the first one with:

```
F(&x);
```

You're invoking the "address of" operator. Effectively this is passing the memory address of `x`. Functionally it's very similar to a reference, but not the same thing.